# TypeError: cannot read property 'channels' of undefined

Tags: discord.js

im not experienced in javascript, i followed some tutorials to have different commands in separated files and they work fine, but i cannot fix an error in a msg command:

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'msg',
    description: 'sends a message to any channel the bot can access',
    execute(message, args){
        
        var msg = args.slice(1);
        msg = msg.join(" ");
        //let channel = Vot.channels.cache.get(args[1])
       let server = args[0]
       
       if(!server) return message.channel.send(msg);
       if(!msg) return message.reply("where is the message");

Vot.channels.cache.get(server).send(msg);
 }
}
```

its supposed to be `.@msg (channel_id) <message>`, sending the message to the desired channel
(it worked before in a switch statement in the main file) i have tried solutions from other questions like `const { client } = require('../Server.js')` at the top but it didnt work, are there any other options?

Comment: Looks like `Vot` is undefined. Where are you assigning a value to it?

Comment: it is in the main file as a constant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `message.client` instead of `Vot`:

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'msg',
    description: 'sends a message to any channel the bot can access',
    execute(message, args){
        
        var msg = args.slice(1);
        msg = msg.join(" ");
        //let channel = message.client.channels.cache.get(args[1])
       let server = args[0]
       
       if(!server) return message.channel.send(msg);
       if(!msg) return message.reply("where is the message");

message.client.channels.cache.get(server).send(msg);
 }
}
```